# Managing parameters in Cloudformation template

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I was deploying a cloudformation template (pre-build and provided by AWS) and was looking for a way to control the parameters (i.e. update it on regular basis with new parameters). I was wondering if there is a programmatic best practice to manage this?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean, the source code of the template itself, e.g. changing default values or adding new parameters?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update an existing stack, you can use the aws-cli and run the `aws cloudformation update-stack` command with an `--parameters` argument that specifies the parameters you want. You can also update the template itself with `--template-body` or `--template-url`, if needed.

Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/update-stack.html

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `aws cloudformation deploy`
Something like this

```
aws cloudformation deploy \
  --template-file ./template.yaml \
  --s3-bucket ${s3_bucket_name} \
  --s3-prefix ${cf-templates} \
  --stack-name ${stackName} \
  --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM \
  --no-fail-on-empty-changeset \
  --parameter-overrides par1=${par1value} par2=${par2value} \
  --tags tag1=tag1value tag2=tag2value \
  --profile test_profile
```

Comment: Is it possible to store the parameters on a JSON file in S3?

Comment: @bazooka720 No, it is not. I guess